# How to read letters such as $\mathbb A$, $\mathbb B$, etc., or $\mathfrak A$, $\mathfrak B$, etc.?

Tags: soft-question, pronunciation

This is a soft question. We can read the letters $\bf A$, $\bf B$, etc. as bold A, bold B, etc. We can read the letters $\textit{A}$, $\textit{B}$, etc. as italic A, italic B, etc. We can read the letters $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, etc. as calligraphic A, calligraphic B, etc. But how do we read letters such as $\mathbb A$, $\mathbb B$, etc., or $\mathfrak A$, $\mathfrak B$, etc.?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{A}, \mathbb{B}$ reads 'Blackboard bold A, Blackboard bold B' and $\mathfrak{A}, \mathfrak{B}$ reads 'Fraktur A, Fraktur B'.

Comment: I usually just pronounce them as $A$, $B$ etc. It's rare to ''speak matematics'' without any support of written text, either in a book or on a blackboard, so it rarely causes any misunderstandings.

Comment: I would say blackboard bold A or script A, respectively.

Comment: Considering the TeX language, I usually speak *bb A* or *cal A* or *frak A*, since we use `\mathbb`, `\mathcal` or `\mathfrak`.

Comment: @Clayton (and others who suggested 'script' for Gothic): How would you read $\mathscr A$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Exactly the same, actually. I tend not to get hung up on specifics. If the notation calls for it, I would use $A_1$, $A_2$, etc. as opposed to using the same letter in different fonts for multiple meanings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

$\Bbb A$ is blackboard A; $\frak A$ is Gothic A.

If there is only one $A$ being used, though, we read it as A regardless to the font.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, there are many A's that I have to use, on the board...

Comment: That's an A?  I always thought it was a U...

Comment: @Greg: Yeah, I remember finding that out... I had the exact same reaction!

Answer (score 92):

If there's [a reason you choose to call them all A's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284201/how-to-read-letters-such-as-mathbb-a-mathbb-b-etc-or-mathfrak-a#comment620185_284204), there's presumably a reason why some of them are fraktur, some of them are black board, and some of them are calligraphic.

Then don't read the font. Read the **meaning**. For example, when I write

> $g(v_1,v_2) = \langle \mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_2\rangle$ where $\mathfrak{g}_1,\mathfrak{g}_2\in \mathfrak{G}$ correspond to $v_1,v_2\in T_p\mathcal{G}$

I **don't** read

> italic gee of vee one and vee two is equal to the angle bracket of frak gee one and frak gee 2 where frak gee 1 and frak gee 2 belong to frak big gee and correspond to vee 1 and vee 2 in tee-pee cal gee.

That's completely incomprehensible!

I read

> The action of the metric gee on vectors vee 1 and vee 2 is set to be equal to the Killing form acting on gee 1 and gee 2, where gee 1 and gee 2 are elements of the Lie algebra gee corresponding to the tangent vectors vee 1 and vee 2 in the tangent space at point pee of the Lie group gee.

In other words, the usual reason one uses different fonts is to help distinguish between different classes of objects (and in some case isolate special objects like $\mathbb{R}$ for the real numbers). In that case, when you are reading the text, you should **speak the name of the class, not the name of the font**.

Comment: Plus 10+ for this blast of common sense!

Comment: I beg to disagree, you're mixing up different stuff. Of course, I second with you on the _general_ principle. But in my situation it's easier to read $\mathbb A$ as "bb A".

Comment: I see that you have voided your bladder since the comment on my comment. The point is `p` now, not `pee`. :-)

Comment: @Asaf: thanks for the correction.

Comment: Yes, sir! ${}{}{}$

Comment: I should also add that numbers below $10$ should be written as words, so it should be "gee one and gee two"... :-) But I won't twist your arm to do that.

Comment: @Asaf: you have even more rep on the site than I, _surely_ you don't have to twist my arm to [achieve  your desired outcome](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit). `:-)`

Comment: Generally I have the higher rep. but this is what you would say, and I wouldn't want to change the way *you* say it! I am also just poking at you because you have "point pee". Is that from not drinking enough water? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: you and I both know what we prefer to drink instead of water. `:-)` But let's cut this out. We should set an example for new users about keeping comments on topic.

Comment: +1, because Voltaire was right: common sense is not so common. At least you still have it.

Answer (score 5):

It's surely a cultural thing, but I've heard $\frak{A}$ referred to as "fraktur A" more frequently, although I do hear "gothic" occasionally. On a similar note, I'm increasingly hearing people actually say the names of TeX commands, even for symbols (not just fonts).

For instance, I have a professor who says "sim-eek" every time he write $\simeq$ (LaTeX command simeq.)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is just acceptable to say "A" and "B"...

It is quite rare that you have to read out aloud any maths that has the same letter appearing in two different fonts like this.

Comment: Please read out loud the following sentence: $p\in\Bbb P\subseteq\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: "Small pee is an element of pee which is a subset of the powerset of A"?

Comment: If I were teaching a class, I'd read that as "let p be a subset of A chosen in the family big p" (or something similar according to context)

Comment: Yes but how often does such a sentence come up in everyday maths? Also usually there is a bit of context which allows you to get round having to read it exactly as it is written...for example "our subset $p$ of $A$"

Answer (score 4):

Depending on context, you may choose to
(1) use the font name, include the style variation when applicable: "Blackboard bold A", as in this discussion:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488/blackboard-bold-characters
(2) use just the style variation when the font does not need to be explicitly stated: "Bold A"
(3) In mathematics specifically, certain fonts of certain letters have standard usage. cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols. In this case, it would typically be read as what they mean. eg. $\mathbb P$(X)=1 might be read as "The probability of the event X occurring is equal to 1." or x $\in\mathbb N$ as "x, a natural number".

Answer (score 4):

I find "reading" a bit vague. Are you reading those letter while lecturing? Are you reading that to a colleague out of some text? Are you reading that over the phone to somebody who is checking a TeX source file?

Different situation require different approaches.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer. Giving a "reading" for each of the cases you've enumerated would make for a good answer.