# When should we use `\frak{...}` in LaTeX

Tags: article-writing

I saw in a note that when writing a paper some notations must be written by `\frak{   }`, in LaTeX, I want to know what the meaning of **some notations** is, and where I can find a source for these types of points of writing? For example, if $R$ is a local ring we write it's maximal ideal as $\frak {m}$

Comment: In principle just a way to get more symbols when you run out of latin and greek letters. There are some conventions which assign similar meaning to similar symbols, but those depend very much on the area of mathematics the work covers.

Comment: For LaTeX and in equations, I suppose it should rather be `\mathfrak`. Anyway, you should use that whenever you need fraktur letters. Fraktur is (for example) often used for ideals and sometimes for vectors, but mostly it is a matter of taste or local conventions.

Comment: I don't think this question is about *how* you typeset Fraktur in LaTeX, but about mathematical writing conventions. (*When* should I use Fraktur instead of the Latin or Greek alphabet?) So I don't think [tex.se] is a good place for it.

Comment: *"I saw in a note that ... some notations ..."* – an exact quote of that note would be helpful.

Comment: [Atiyah-MacDonald](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Commutative-Algebra-Addison-Wesley-Mathematics/dp/0201407515) uses $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}, \mathfrak{m}, \mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ to signify ideals of a ring.

Comment: See http://www.abstractmath.org/Word%20Press/?p=9481 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87627/fraktur-symbols-for-lie-algebras-mathfrakg-etc.

Comment: @pGroups On TeX.StackExchange this would be considered off-topic, I'm afraid. *When* to use `\mathfrak` is not a TeX question, but it pertains to style.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Blackboard bold, Bold, Fraktur, and Reserved Variable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072685/). Linking for the exhortation to use _semantic_ macros for notation, as in `\newcommand[1]{\Ideal}{\mathfrak{#1}}` in the preamble, and then `\Ideal{a}`, etc. in the body of the document. Hard-coding `\mathfrak` in the document body is _brittle_ (e.g., if you send the paper to a publisher with rigid in-house notational conventions). Nowadays, hard-coding fonts is a (common!) rookie mistake. (That said, I myself used LaTeX for years before the point sank in.)

Comment: \frak S, i.e. $\frak S$ used to be a simple way to typeset fractur letter S in AMSTeX. I am not sure whether AMSTeX has any support any longer.